# WebAppConfigurationImpl memory leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, websphere-8

about every 2-3-4 weeks I have to restart our development and sometimes also the test WAS server as it gets OutOfMemoryError. There is only one applicaton installed on the WAS instance which is using spring/hibernate. The OutOfMemoryError occurs always while a new version of the application is being installed via jython scripts. It goes well like 20 times, then it gets an OutOfMemoryError. I have increased the max heap size to 1GB but the only result was, it took more time (or app installation) until the memory got full.
Looking at the dumps with heap analyzer I found the following leak suspect:

```
Leak suspect    672 338 752 bytes (62,84 %) of Java heap is used by 15 instances of java/util/WeakHashMap$Entry
Contains 14 instances of the following leak suspects:
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 26 033 976 bytes at 0xc7e5970
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 26 136 480 bytes at 0x832e0e8
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 30 268 008 bytes at 0x1a6fabb0
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 26 059 488 bytes at 0xf1e69e8
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 26 076 544 bytes at 0x18b6bd50
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 26 398 752 bytes at 0x1fd7ae18
- array of java/lang/ref/Reference holding 25 967 856 bytes at 0x15545cf0
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 26 400 856 bytes at 0x2f948228
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 26 351 608 bytes at 0x262ac718
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 26 074 376 bytes at 0x15382010
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 26 073 152 bytes at 0x1350bb60
- array of java/util/HashMap$Entry holding 140 723 440 bytes at 0x1607d88
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 26 420 688 bytes at 0x2de7bd60
- com/ibm/ws/webcontainer/webapp/WebAppConfigurationImpl holding 27 413 768 bytes at 0x25081e88


Installed Product
IBM WebSphere Application Server
Version               8.5.5.7
IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition (Optional)
Version               7.0.4.1
```

Unfortunately I haven't found any helpful about WebAppConfigurationImpl. Has any of you experienced similar problem? Since it is part of an ibm package, should I report it to IBM as a potential bug?

Comment: You probably should create a PMR in IBM Support.

Comment: Likely something holding onto the old application classloaders, you'll need to have support look at your full dumps in a case like this.